# Get all entities in which at least one part of its field starts with some string parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a dept field that is an undefined number of strings representing postal codes, delimited by the character `-`.

Example:

> 35000-35200-35700

How could I get all entities in which at least one part of dept field starts with some string parameter?

```
class Town {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dept", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dept;
}
```

I would like to have something like this, with `35` as `$str` parameter for example:

```
$em->getRepository("Town")->findByDeptAutoComplete($str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I were you, I would store these postal codes in another entity. (I'm assuming your strings delimited by `-` are postal codes.)

But to respond to your question about *finding entities in which at least one part of dept field starts with some string parameter*, you can test if `town.dept` contains `-35` (the delimiter + the department 35, in example), then test the start of the string (to catch the first postal code):

```
public function findByDeptAutoComplete($dept) {
    $queryResult = $this->createQueryBuilder('town')
            ->select('town')
            ->where("LOCATE(CONCAT('-', :dept),  town.dept) > 0 OR SUBSTRING(town.dept, 1, LENGTH(:dept)) = :dept")
            ->setParameter('dept', $dept)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
    ;
    return $queryResult;
}
```

Comment: yes it helped me thanks a lot. But your code has a typo. Also you forgot "->getResult()" and the "->select()" wasn't mandatory. Update it and I'll accpet your answer. Here is what I used : public function findByDeptAutoComplete($dept) {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('town')
                        ->where("LOCATE(CONCAT('-', :dept),  town.dept) > 0 OR SUBSTRING(town.dept, 1, LENGTH(:dept)) = :dept")
                        ->setParameter('dept', $dept)->getQuery();

        $towns = $query->getResult();
        return $towns;
    }

Comment: @TrtG you're right for the typo, fixed :) For the "select", I find it helps to read the code, I've left it. For the use of `'` or `"`, I prefer `'` as PHP doesn't try to interpret variables in string, but again, it's more a matter of choice.

Comment: for me it didn't work when surrounding the where clause with simple quotes because of the first param of CONCAT which needed to be simple quotes.

Comment: also the typo I was talking about is still there (; at the and of "where" line)

Comment: @TrtG my bad, sorry, I've correted it :)